# Syntax for if/else statement in Haml - unexpected keyword else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, syntax-error, haml

I just switched to HAML and converting my erb to haml. I am experiencing an error (unexpected keyword else) when setting up the code as I think it should look:

```
= if signed_in?
  %li= link_to "Users", '#'
  %li#fat-menu.dropdown
    %a.dropdown-toggle{ href: '#', data: { toggle: "dropdown" } } 
      Account
      %b.caret
    %ul.dropdown-menu
      %li= link_to "Profile", current_user
      %li= link_to "Settings", '#'
      %li.divider
      %li= link_to "Log out", signout_path, method: "delete"
= else
  %li= link_to "Log in", signin_path
```

I have tried a number of things, but I can't seem to tackle the syntax error. I am sure it is a pretty basic thing for somebody who knows HAML. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Use `-` instead of `=` before `if` and `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `=` with `-` before `if` and `else`.

Comment: Nice!! Encounter Marek :)

Answer (score 2):

HAML is indentation based , and the parser can be tricky.You don't need to use `- end` in Haml. Use indentation instead.In Haml,a block begins whenever the indentation is increased after a Ruby evaluation command. It ends when the indentation decreases.Sample if else block as follows.

```
- if condition
  = something
- else
  = something_else
```